# JS loop iterates but value not passed

Tags: javascript

The loop in getBottles() iterates but does not pass value of totalBottles to main(). 
Im new to JS and could use some help with finer details.when running the script returns 0 for totalBottles. Please help.

```
//main function calls other functions
function main(){
   var totalBottles = 0;
   var counter = 1;
   var todayBottles = 0;
   var totalPayout = 0;
   var keepGoing = "y";

   while(keepGoing == "y"){
      getBottles(totalBottles, todayBottles, counter);
      calcPayout(totalPayout, totalBottles);
      printInfo(totalBottles, totalPayout);
      inputStr = prompt("Do you want to run the program again? (Enter y for yes)");
      keepGoing = inputStr;
   }
}
//getBottles function gets loops to get # bottles each day for a week
function getBottles(totalBottles, todayBottles, counter){
   while(counter <= 7){
      inputStr = prompt("Enter number of bottles returned for the day:");
      todayBottles = parseFloat(inputStr);
      totalBottles = totalBottles + todayBottles;
      counter = counter + 1;
   }  return totalBottles;
}

//calcPayout function calculates payout for all bottles returned in a week
function calcPayout(totalPayout, totalBottles){
   totalPayout = 0;
   totalPayout = totalBottles * .10;
   return totalPayout;
}

//printInfo function displays totsl bottles and total payout for week
function printInfo(totalBottles, totalPayout){
   alert("Total bottles returned this week: " + totalBottles);
   alert("Total payout this week: $" + totalPayout.toFixed(2));
}  

main();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your getBottles function isn't modifying the totalBottles variable you declare in main because it's being shadowed by the local variable you declare as a parameter in getBottles:

```
function getBottles(totalBottles, todayBottles, counter) {...} // totalBottles here is a local variable to getBottles as are the other parameters
```

totalBottles in this function declaration becomes a local variable for this function, meaning that any modification to totalBottles is only known about by the body of this function. You return this value from the function, but since you never assign that return value to anything, the value is essentially discarded. The same is true for your other functions, for example, calcPayout. You have a couple of options. You can either change your function signature, so that you're no longer shadowing the variables being declared in main with local variables declared as function parameters:

```
function getBottles() {...}
```

By doing this, you wouldn't pass the variables in to the function, but rather just use them from within the scope of main():

```
getBottles();
```

With this, getBottles forms a closure over the totalBottles, todayBottles, and counter variables, and those variables will be used and modified by getBottles. Your other options is assigning the return value:

```
var bottles = getBottles(totalBottles, todayBottles, counter);
```

That value can then be passed into the next function. Keep in mind that you'll need to do the same thing with your other functions.